# Pandas groupby operation returned object, but no visual

Tags: python, pandas

Very new to Pandas (2 days) and ran the following groupby command on my Academy Awards data set.

```
df[(df.Award == 'Best Actress') & (df.Winner == 1.0)].groupby('Name')
```

I received the following output, which usually precedes a visualisation, but not this time.

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x1166b8cc0>
```

I was expecting a chart of all actresses who have won an Oscar for "Best (Leading) Actress" grouped by their respective names.

Why not chart?

Edit:

Data look like this . . .

```
    Year    Ceremony    Award   Winner  Name                Film
0   1928    1           Actor   0.0    Richard Barthelmess  The Noose
1   1928    1           Actor   1.0     Emil Jannings       The Last Command
2   1928    1           Actress 0.0     Louise Dresser      A Ship Comes In
3   1928    1         Actress   1.0     Janet Gaynor        7th Heaven
4   1928    1         Actress   0.0     Gloria Swanson      Sadie Thompson
5   1928    1         Art Dir   0.0     Rochus Gliese       Sunrise
```

Comment: Can you add some small date set and desired output?

Comment: Or do you need `df[(df.Award == 'Best Actress') & (df.Winner == 1.0)].groupby('Name').size().plot()` ?

Comment: Because that's the object returned by the `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` method. You need to use other methods, like `agg`, to "take the next step."

Comment: and need how many Names is 'Best Actress' and Winner is 1.0?

Comment: Thanks, all. I got it. Agg() was what I needed to get the chart I wanted, but I'm very happy to know about size(), plot(), and how to take "next steps" in general!

Answer (score 3):

> I received the following output, which usually precedes a visualisation, but not this time.

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x1166b8cc0>
```

---

This is **not** the same as what precedes a visualization.
This **is** the textual representation of the `pandas` `DataFrameGroupBy` object.

In Python, everything is an object.  However, not every object has an intuitive way to present itself to a screen.  There exists a method named `__repr__` among others that control the textual representation of that object.  In this case `df.groupby('col_name')` returns a `DataFrameGroupBy` object.  That object's `__repr__` method returns the string you see `<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x1166b8cc0>`.  It's fairly typical for that method to wrap a generic description of the class that produced the object with `<>`.

It is that `<>` that looks familiar. `matplotlib` outputs the `__repr__` for an axis:  `df.plot()` produces  `<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x11a2b9cf8>`.  As a matter of fact, you can suppress that output with a semi-colon `df.plot();`

---

That all said, I'm still not sure what you were expecting chart wise

```
df.query('Award == "Actress"').set_index('Name').Winner.plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, explanation are not easy for me - maybe becasue not native english.

Comment: @jezrael and still, you do a very good job.  However, I am always willing to jump in and help explain one of your excellent answers when I perceive a potential language issue.  I hope you don't mind when I do that.

Comment: Yes, I see it yesterday. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate some function like [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) if need count of filtered column `Name` and for plot function [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html) or [`plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
df[(df.Award == 'Best Actress') & (df.Winner == 1.0)].groupby('Name').size().plot() 

df[(df.Award == 'Best Actress') & (df.Winner == 1.0)].groupby('Name').size().plot.bar()
```

Or use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.loc[(df.Award == 'Best Actress') & (df.Winner == 1.0), 'Name'].value_counts().plot()
```

EDIT:

I think very nice tutorial is [10 Minutes to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).

Comment: Nice 10 mintues to pandas link.